# How to add a simple product with more than 1 option to Cart?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, addtocart

I am trying to add a product from a custom page to the cart. I have the Configurable and also simple and I have the values of the options and also the IDs of the options.

I tried to use:

```
/path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=$pid&qty=$qty&options[$id]=$value
```

in the way

```
/path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=$pid&qty=$qty&options[$id]=$value&options[$id]=$value
```

Did not work out .

Then I tried this :

```
/path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=$pid&qty=$qty&options[$id1,$id2]=$value1,$value2
```

This also did not work out. What Am I missing?

Any help will be appretiated.

Cheers

Comment: you can not add custom options of product at cart level

Comment: What error msg are you getting?

Comment: I am not adding Custom options. Thear are attribute options from Dropdowns. It says all the options are not sent to add the product, so an option is missing, it redirects me to the product page and tells me to select all options needed. They are only two and I am sending both of the,. When I sent it with the Simple product ID I got an other error , getProduct() function on a null object. So Two cases, two different Errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the Add to Cart network calls and I saw that it is not options but super_attribute.

Last code I used is :

```
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>checkout/cart/add?product=<?php echo $product->getEntityId(); ?>&qty=1&super_attribute[145]=<?php echo $realSimple->getData("liegeflaeche") ?>&super_attribute[146]=<?php echo $realSimple->getData("haertegrad") ?>">
                <img src="" alt="product5" />ADD TO CART
            </a>
```

And it works like hell.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using magento v1.7.*, then to add simple product with more than 1 option to Cart try

```
$product_id = 165;

$option_id1 = 424;
$option_val1 = 6699;

$option_id2 = 433;
$option_val2 = 6830;
```

Eg

```
http://www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=165&options[424]=6699&options[433]=6830
```

To get the above values go to your product page and look up the values... eg.

```
<select name="options[424]" id="select_424" class=" required-entry product-custom-option front-finishes" title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option value="6698">Red</option>
  <option value="6699">Green</option>
```

If your still having issue then double check if you have any third party module that extend your cart functionality.

**Adding a Configurable Product to the Cart via Querystring**

For adding a Configurable Product to the Cart via Querystring you need a url format like following

```
http://www.your_domain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=68&qty=1&super_attribute[528]=55&super_attribute[525]=56
```

See [Adding a Product to the Cart via Querystring](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)

Comment: Just one clearence on the issue, The Product Id is from Configurable or from Simple ?

Comment: Simple product, to add configurable `.../checkout/cart/add?product=68&qty=1&super_attribute[528]=55&super_attribute[525]=56`

Comment: A bit late my Friend. I already solved my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Issue:

There are issue with `form key` in both all of case you need .in magento `cartController.php`  at `addAction` magento us checked form key using `_validateFormKey()` function.if it validate then product is not added `in cart`

If you want add a product in cart then you need  to create proper product cart url using below
function

```
Mage:helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($productOject,$parameter=array());
```

Comment: Does 'form key' validation affect v1.7.*?

Comment: no..magento 1.7 do not check form key

Comment: What are the values or what is the build up of `$parameter=array()` in this function? We want to add 1 child product of a configurable parent product